# "contentMode: .fill" is not working on iOS 15 | SwiftUI Xcode 13

Tags: image, swiftui, fill, ios15

I recently updated to Xcode 13 and I'm facing an issue with one image in my App

This is the same view with the same code in the same device but different iOS versions:
[image]

The image I'm using is this (Is a screenshoot instead of original image because original is over 2MB max limit image size of Stack Overflow):

[image]

The code:

```
struct HomeView: View {
@State private var navigateTo: Int? = Links.NIL

// Navigation in root and accent color change.
@Binding var rootViewLinks: RootView.Links
@State var navigationAccentColor: Color = Color(R.color.d_primary()!)

var body: some View {
    
    NavigationView{
        VStack{
            //Logo and title
            HStack{
                Image(R.image.ic_logo_miloto_white.name)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 48, height: 56, alignment: .center)
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                
                Text("miloto")
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.system(size: 48))
                    .labelStyle(CustomLabelStyle())
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            //Welcome text
            Text(R.string.localizable.homeSlogan())
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .labelStyle(CustomLabelStyle())
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding()
            
            //Action buttons
            HStack{
                //ACCESS NAVIGATION
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: AccessView(rootViewLinks: self.$rootViewLinks, navigationAccentColor: self.$navigationAccentColor),
                    tag: Links.ACCESS,
                    selection: $navigateTo){
                         Button(R.string.localizable.login_text()){
                            navigateTo = Links.ACCESS
                         }
                         .buttonStyle(PrimaryInvertedButtonStyle_W())
                }
                
                //REGISTER NAVIGATION
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: RegisterView(rootViewLinks: self.$rootViewLinks, navigationAccentColor: self.$navigationAccentColor),
                    tag: Links.REGISTER,
                    selection: $navigateTo){
                        Button(R.string.localizable.register_text()){
                            navigateTo = Links.REGISTER
                        }
                        .buttonStyle(PrimaryButtonStyle_W())
                }
            }.padding(.horizontal)
            
            //Tour text
            NavigationLink(
                destination: TourView(pages: TourPage.getHomeTutorialPages()),
                tag: Links.TOUR,
                selection: $navigateTo
            ) {
                HStack {
                    Text(R.string.localizable.tour_text())
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .labelStyle(CustomLabelStyle())
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                    Image(R.image.ic_plane.name)
                }
                .padding(.vertical)
            }
        }
        .background(
            Image(R.image.bg_home_big.name)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(nil, contentMode: .fill)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
        )
    }
    .accentColor(navigationAccentColor)
}
```

But you should focus on this:

```
        .background(
            Image(R.image.bg_home_big.name)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(nil, contentMode: .fill)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
        )
```

**Why is image fill not working on iOS 15? Is this a bug? **

Comment: I don't think it is a bug. Try to add `.ignoresSafeArea()` to `NavigationView` as well.

Comment: "The image I'm using is this"  Just tell us what the image size is and what the size of the `View` is.

Comment: The image size is 1440x2688. I dont get what you mean with size of the `View`

Comment: adding `.ignoreSafeArea()` to `NavigationView` does not fix the problem.

Comment: May it be because you set the background of the stackVIew and not the actual navigationView? Can you try moving the entire background block to where you declare the accentColor?

Comment: I've already try it. It does not load the image, leaving the background white.

Comment: I don't know if it is a bug, but you could try 
something like this, instead of `background(...)`:

        `NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Image(R.image.bg_home_big.name).resizable().ignoresSafeArea()
                VStack { ... }
            }
        }`